# How can I avoid the general Exception thrown by the Server-class in Jetty?

Tags: java, exception, jetty, embedded-jetty

[Jetty](http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty/) can be used as a library to embed a servlet-server into your application. To do that, you create an instance of the class [Server](http://www.mortbay.org/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/Server.html) and call start at some point. This method throws Exception. Catching or throwing a pure Exception (not a specialized subclass) is bad style. Does anyone know, how I can avoid this and get a Jetty-server in my application running without handling this general Exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catching `Exception` is bad practice *unless only `Exception` is thrown*. There is no workaround for it. Catching distinct subclasses of `Exception` has the disadvantage of possibly missing out on some of them.

---

What is the meaning of Jetty failing to start in your application? You can have multiple approaches:

**Decide at the component level that you should proceeed**

```
try { 
    server.start();
    reportingAvailable = true;
} catch ( Exception e ) { 
    log("Jetty failed to start. Reporting will we unavailable", e);
}
```

**Treat it as a fatal exception**

```
try { 
    server.start();
} catch ( Exception e ) { 
    throw new RuntimeException("Jetty failed to start", e);
}
```

**Treat it as a recoverable exception**

```
try { 
    server.start();
} catch ( Exception e ) { 
    throw new JettyFailedToStartException(e); // JettyFailedToStartException !instanceof RuntimeException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would *strongly* advise you to handle it somehow.

If Jetty can't start (e.g. bind to its nominated port) then you're going to want to manage that somehow. At the very least log this so you know you don't have a web server running. Perhaps retry after a while ?

The point is that Jetty is unable to start and you should care about that.